# What are the best sites to display your data science skills & projects?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, beginner

What are the best sites to display your data science skills & projects? Obviously there's kaggle, but any others that recruiters look at?

Comment: github & linkedin

Answer (score 1):

1. LinkedIn
2. Github
3. Personal Website (of course)
4. Coderbits (not popular, but you can display your profile link on the resume/LinkedIn)
5. Kaggle

Comment: I think number 3 is really good, because it let's you investigate anything you'd like.  It also forces you to work on storytelling & design, aspects of good data science that are often overlooked.